# Blazor server side problem share javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm developing my project with Blazor Server-side.
While I develop, I used javascript code to implement things that hard to implement by C#.

However, I'm facing something weird situation. (I guess it is problem for javascript)

Suppose there are 2 users(A, B). When 'A' user do some action that call javascript code, if 'B' user into same page, 'A' users action affects to 'B' user.

I implemented web page that have 3d scene with threejs. As I explained above, when User 'A' move some object with mouse event(mousemove, mousedown..), if User 'B' accesses the same page, 3d objects of B are moved to the location where User 'A' moved.
Originally, when user access to web page I developed, 3d objects's position should be 0,0,0.

**My Guess**

- I don't use prototype or class(use variable and functions globally. I'm new to javascript.. )
- Javascript runs on server-side(share resources??, If then, how can I solve it)

I'm guessing the javascript would be problem, but if you have any other opinions, would you please share?

**Edited**

I've solved this problem using `DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);`

C#

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        //send created instance to javascript
        var dotNetObjRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("SetObjectRef", dotNetObjRef);
    }
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}

[JSInvokable]
public async Task enableSomething(bool bEnable)
{
   var something = bEnable;
}

//== before edit
//[JSInvokable]
//public static async Task enableSomethingStatic(bool bEnable)
//{   
//    var something = bEnable;
//}
```

Javascript

```
var objectRef;
function SetObjectRef(ref) {
    objectRef = ref;
}

//call c# function
objectRef.invokeMethodAsync("enableSomething", true);
```

It was problem of 'static' method as I guessed.
If you declare C# method called from javascript as 'static' and this method changes something of UI variable, this method can affect another users.

So I create instance of current page and send it javascript and when I need to call C# methods from javascript, I call methods using created instance.

Is there any problem or issue, please share it.
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript runs client side only.  I don't see how two windows, let alone two users, would share data.

Almost for sure, the problem is that you are injecting a singleton service-- which means the server will use one instance for all users.

If so, you have two choices:

(1) add logic to your singleton service to incorporate users.  (For example, a dictionary with UserID/Property name for key, and a column for Value)

(2) go to `Startup.cs` and change the suspect singleton service to .AddScoped(), which will create a new instance for each user.

For right now, I think the latter solution will solve your problem immediately.  However, don't underestimate the value of Singletons-- they'll be very useful for other things.

Comment: thank you for your kind guidance. I tried to change singleton services to `addscoped`, however it didn't work. So, I look around my code again and again and I found one questionable part. I guess the problem is that the [JSInvokable] function is declared 'static'.  As opposed to IJSRuntime, it is used when calling a C# function from JavaScript.
It would be called when user try to move 3D object for send position information to UI.
Calling a'static' function from javascript, could this be a problem?
Thank you again for you answer.

Comment: Oh, is this a static class with its own variables?  Why don't you try removing static, registering it as a service instead and using dependency injection with Scoped?  Basically-- do what I thought you were already doing. :D

Comment: Um.. It is not class, method. [JSInvokable] It's not a class, it's a function. This is used to pass variables used in JavaScript from JavaScript to the C# area. And It should be declared with 'static' keyword to call from javascript. 

For example

**In js** 

`DotNet.invokeMethodAsync("ProjectName", "setCurrentState", true);`

**In C#** 

`[JSInvokable]
public static async Task setCurrentState(bool bEnable)
{... }`

Comment: I see.  Then I have to say I don't know why this person's having state persistence among users.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I've solved this problem and I wrote it how to solve it *Edited* in my question.

Comment: Nice!  In that case thanks for marking my answer, but I think you should unmark it and choose your own!  So in the end, was it that 'objectRef' was keeping its value?

Comment: Yes, it will depend on how you implement it, but I used it as a global variable in JavaScript. I guessed 'marking' is used when answer is helpful for me. However, from what you commented, it doesn't seem like what I guessed, so I'll remove the marking. But I don't know how to mark mine. Could you tell me?

Comment: I think I see what happened. . . you used the same browser window, logged out, logged into a new account, and that happened, right?  What if you open a new browser tab, does it still do it?

Comment: I think you thought that is problem of cache or something else right? But I and my co-workers tested  with different ID in their own seats.

Comment: That's right.  It turns out that in Blazor when you say "static," you'd better really mean it, hey? ;D

Comment: Oh man! I was having the same trouble using a second connection with SignalR (I removed the SIngleton before) and I was struggling with, basically removing the f"..ing "static" word solved my problems