# Blazor Server using SignalR is not working (Project was WASM before)

Tags: blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I had a project built with a WASM structure where I was using SignalR to make the App work in RealTime, my SignalR was built using JavaScript (this part is still working on Blazor Server) everything was working perfectly but I changed to a Blazor Server due loading time on the client, and I have this problematic issue.

The problem right now is that when a "UserOne" opens a browser, the connection is made, and everything is working. Still, after another "UserTwo" opens the browser, the events stop triggering on the "UserOne."

As I said, this is a post-migration problem and might be related to the case Blazor Server uses SignalR to update the views, and somehow "UserTwo" take over the connection made by "UserOne."

I leave code here of my SignalR made on JavaScript:

```
$("#app").aeListConnection({
    access_token: token,
    application: application,
    url: url,
    onconnect: function (data) {
        DotNet.invokeMethodAsync(WebAssemblyName, "ConnectIdFromSignalRMultipleConnection", data.id);
        if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("login") > -1) {
            DotNet.invokeMethodAsync(WebAssemblyName,"ConnectionReloaded");
        }
    },
    onpreview: function (data) {
        functionToExecute = createFunction("DataFromSignalR")
        console.log("preview and exec " + functionToExecute);
        DotNet.invokeMethodAsync(WebAssemblyName,functionToExecute, data);
    },
    onfeedback: function (data) {
        functionToExecute = createFunction("FeedbackFromSignalR")
        console.log("feedback and exec " + functionToExecute + " Status: " + data.Status + " UserId: " + data.UserId);
        DotNet.invokeMethodAsync(WebAssemblyName,functionToExecute, data.Status);
    },
    onupdate: function (data, msg) {
        functionToExecute = createFunction("DataFromSignalR")
        console.log("update and exec " + functionToExecute + " " + msg);
        document.getElementById("CurrentBid").innerHTML = data.CurrentBid;

        DotNet.invokeMethodAsync(WebAssemblyName,functionToExecute, data);
    }
});
```

The code above is running perfectly and catching all the changes; the code on the OnUpdate event will trigger this function on my Blazor Project to the latest user who has loaded the website:

```
    [JSInvokable]
    public static void DataFromSignalRLotDetails(dynamic value)
    {
        BridgeFunctionDataFromSignalR.Invoke(value);
    }
```

```
        private async Task DataFromSignalRAsync(dynamic value)
        {
            {
                //Run some code here
            }
        }
```

Many thanks in advance.

I have tried updating the view from JavaScript directly without passing the data to Blazor and then updating the view, this worked, but I don't want to change my whole structure because it will cause a lot of hours, and it won't be good for the future.

The JSInvokable is triggered only in the browser of the one who loaded the latest.

Service Register:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

// setting client host environment 
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHostEnvironment>(
    new HostingEnvironment() { EnvironmentName = builder.Environment.EnvironmentName });

builder.Logging.AddConfiguration(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("Logging")
);

builder.Services.AddScoped<ILotService, LotService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuctionService, AuctionService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMemberService, MemberService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUseCasesService, UseCasesService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IContactService, ContactService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICountryService, CountryService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILanguageService, LanguageService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPaymentService, PaymentService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IInvoiceService, InvoiceService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUmbracoService, UmbracoService>();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, AuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddIntersectionObserver();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PageHistoryState>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ManageSignalRState>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CategorySingleton>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuctionSingleton>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<UmbracoSingleton>();
builder.Services.AddHeadElementHelper();
builder.Services.AddSocialMediaSharing();
builder.Services.AddLocalization();



var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "id-ID" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
} 

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Probably wrong DI lifetime somewhere - maybe `BridgeFunctionDataFromSignalR` - can you include your service registering

Comment: @MisterMagoo I have included the Services in the post. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Can you show  more about `BridgeFunctionDataFromSignalR` - where it is defined and where clients register handlers?

Comment: @MisterMagoo I solved this problem by following the instructions of this awesome guy here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66683889/blazor-server-side-problem-share-javascript-code. Turns out that the problem is with using "static" invokable methods. 

So I changed my static methods on Blazor, and everything is working now, apparently static methods are shared among the users.